# Using asp-route-{variable} tag helper for an array

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm learning from [this ASP.NET Core Razor Pages tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and I'm struggling to adapt it to my needs. For the pagination links, shortened down to:

```
<a asp-page="./Index"
   asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.Student.PageIndex + 1)"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@Model.CurrentFilter"
   class="btn btn-default">
    Next
</a>
```

I can't find directions how to handle an asp-route-{variable} where variable (currentFilter in the snippet) is an array. For my case, in my view I've adjusted CurrentFilter to be a selectbox with the multiple property, which shows up like this in the URL:

```
https://localhost/Student/?currentFilter=foo&currentFilter=bar
```

Which gets to my model as a string array. I can't find any documentation or solutions around how to use the asp-route tag helper to pass an array into a query string.

Answer (score 0):

The hacky feeling workaround I'm doing until I get a great answer...

I've updated my CSHTML to have use asp-all-route-data.

```
@{
    var nextParms = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    int x = 0;
    nextParms.Add("pageIndex", (Model.Mini.PageIndex + 1).ToString());
    foreach (string item in Model.CurrentFilter)
    {
        nextParms.Add("SearchString" + x, item);
        x++;
    }
}

<a asp-page="./Index"
   asp-all-route-data="nextParms"
   class="btn btn-default">
    Next
</a>
```

then I reconstruct CurrentFilter if I have CurrentFilterN and no CurrentFilter in my OnGet method.

```
        if (CurrentFilter !=null && CurrentFilter .Count()>0)
        {
            //Logic if CurrentFilter exists as normal
        }
        else
        {
           List<string> SearchList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var key in HttpContext.Request.Query)
            {
                if (key.Key.Contains("SearchString"))
                {
                    SearchList.Add(key.Value);
                    string IndividualTag = key.Value;
                }
                //Same logic as above
            }

            CurrentFilter = SearchList.ToArray();
        }
```

So if the user uses the multiselect, CurrentFilter gets set properly. If they hit next, SearchString0, SearchString1, ..., SearchStringN get passed through in the query string which gets parsed out into CurrentFilter.

Feels hacky, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting values to comma-separated string and then using `string.Split(',').Select(s=>int.Parse(s))`